# Объясните на пальцах, в чем отличие Thread, Handler, Runnable и AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Пожалуйста, объясните по простому в чем отличие Thread, Handler, Runnable и AsyncTask?

Comment: вам сюда https://developer.android.com/

Answer (score 3):

На пальцах.

Thread создаём поток + Runnable что будет делать поток

Handler когда и где потоку быть + Message создать связь между потоками

AsyncTask - это всё вместе